# WP8 Panorama Style Settings

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, header, styles, panorama-control

I have a basic Panorama where I have set a style to adjust the App Title, but I would like to adjust a few other things but I don't know what the settings are - or how to find them.

[image: layout sample]

Ideally I'd like the Title not to scroll but I can live with that. The main things I would like to do is make the gap between the header item titles less and also reduce the gap between the headers and the content below them.

Hopefully the screenshot shows what I mean clearly enough.

Comment: Maybe a `Pivot` control is more to your liking?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for - can't believe I missed that lol

Comment: np, you can browse my answers list for multiple ways you can custom that `Pivot` of yours, that's if you don't want to make it look generic :)